# Create Device Pool returning None repsonse - AWSCLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am creating a devicepool using AWS CLI as below

```
aws devicefarm create-device-pool --project-arn arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:826601527641:project:90cbdcb5-4dab-438e-8ff6-e0680b376619 --name Devicepool_viago_android_0310201614131457612089 --description Devicepool_viago_android_0310201614131457612089 --rules '[{"attribute": "ARN", "operator": "EQUALS", "value":"arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2::device:C66D1BC946634884A129A4456EBA0239"}]'
```

I want to create a device pool with only one device.

I am getting error as below

```
A server error (InternalFailure) occurred when calling the CreateDevicePool operation: None
```

I tried the solutions mentioned in other forums but I am not able to succeed in generating a device pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule values [should be stringified](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_Rule.html). Unfortunately, this information isn't properly surfaced in the AWS Device Farm documentation. We are working on making this more visible in the documentation and the API response. Since you're using the AWS CLI, have a look at the [Getting Started with the CLI for Device Farm](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxROO0QM0WSCJX/Get-started-with-the-AWS-Device-Farm-CLI-and-Calabash-Part-1-Creating-a-Device-F) blog post.

This should work:
`aws devicefarm create-device-pool --project-arn "PROJECT_ARN" --name POOL_NAME --rules  '[{"attribute":"ARN", "operator":"IN", "value":"\"DEVICE_ARN\""}]'`

Comment: EQUALS didn't worked for me. IN worked for me. aws devicefarm create-device-pool --project-arn "PROJECT_ARN" --name POOL_NAME --rules  '[{"attribute":"ARN", "operator":"IN", "value":"[\"DEVICE_ARN\"]"}]'

Comment: Odd, CLI command works fine in terminal but when I execute the command through python subprocess, I get error Error parsing parameter '--rules': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'[{"attribute":

Comment: Now I am not, I will take a took at it.

Comment: Excellent. Sounds like you're unblocked. Let me know if you encounter any more issues.