# Creating device pool for a particular set of android phones in aws devicefarm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-espresso, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am trying to run android test using [aws devicefarm](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxROO0QM0WSCJX/Get-started-with-the-AWS-Device-Farm-CLI-and-Calabash-Part-1-Creating-a-Device-F) and the code for creating a device pool is given below.

The CLI command below creates a Device Pool consisting of all available Android devices:

```
[ec2-user]$  aws devicefarm create-device-pool --project-arn
 arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:705582597265:project:2c21a412-bb7b-4657-a28c-d7d78b3888f7
 --name myAndroidDevicePool --rules '[{"attribute": "PLATFORM", "operator": "EQUALS", "value": "\"ANDROID\""}]'
```

But the issue here is, it will run for all android devices, and I only want to run in `LG Nexus 5`. 
Could anyone tell me how we can define for device pool for a single mobile device or set of devices but not all. I couldn't find a clear documentation for it. Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917390/create-device-pool-returning-none-repsonse-awscli/35921768#35921768. This should work: aws devicefarm create-device-pool --project-arn "PROJECT_ARN" --name POOL_NAME --rules  '[{"attribute":"ARN", "operator":"IN", "value":"\"DEVICE_ARN\""}]'

Comment: I have gone through it, and it's not helpful. I just want to test for LG Nexus 5 and not sure how to define the parameters.

Comment: `DEVICE_ARN` is unique for devices right?

Comment: Could you please explain how will I find `DEVICE_ARN` for LG Nexus 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @Rohan mentioned in this comment and to answer your question about identifying the ARN of a device.

1. You can first call [list-devices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-devices.html). This will give you the device ARN for all the devices so you can locate the device ARN for LG Nexus 5.
2. Use that ARN in the rules as ARN parameter.

Since the ARN is a unique identifier of a resource within device farm you should be able to create a device pool with a single device which in your case is LG Nexus 5.

Let me know if you are not able to proceed.

Comment: I used `MANUFACTURER` and provided `LG`, it was working fine for me